# How to sort a JSF 2 dataTable in two ways, by two variable/columns?

Tags: jpa, jsf-2

I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String content;

    private boolean visible;

    private Date displayDate;

}
```

Only one Question can be visible in the database all the time. The requirement for the list in the dataTable is that the first line must be the visible Question and the others must be ordered by displayDate. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is usually performed in DB (model) side, not in JSF (view) side. Your SQL (and equivalently also JPQL) query should be written that way that it returns **exactly** the rows you need, without any necessary postprocessing (the DB is namely endless much more efficient in the selecting job than Java/JSF).

In plain SQL terms, that would be

```
(...) ORDER BY visible DESC, displayDate ASC
```

If you're using JPA, you should surely be able to extract the proper JPQL syntax for that

```
(...) FROM Question q (...) ORDER BY q.visible DESC, q.displayDate ASC
```

Comment: This is exactly the more flexible way to think about this situation. Now I know. Thank you.

Comment: Wow! Just the query (JPQL) you wrote! Worked fine!